# I'm thinking we hug

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood

In this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnJSFn4jbuc) of the movie "Trolls", Cloud Guy says at 1:26

> (1) Now I'm thinking we hug.

In context, I think he means "I'm thinking that we should hug".

Is the verb "hug" in (1) in the present tense or the present subjunctive?

Also, is it possible to say "I think" instead of "I'm thinking" here?

> (2) Now I think we hug.

Comment: This is probably a parenthetical usage; using commas would make this clear [(1') Now, I'm thinking, we hug.] but would disrupt the flow, and I'd say the comma-less version is allowable. So 'hug' is present tense. / 'I'm thinking' is probably used as a hedged version of 'I think'. 'BrE' would probably hedge differently: 'Now I think we should have a hug.'

Comment: 'I think' means this is my opinion, whereas in the quote, it occurs to me as I am weighing all this. He is not suggesting the hug, but pictures that it will soon happen as a matter of course: It seems this is what happens at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an imitation of stage directions.  Cloud guy is brainstorming as would be done in the writers' room.  If one writer were proposing to colleagues a hug at this point in the script, s/he would say,

> Now I'm thinking they hug.

"I'm thinking" means "I'm imagining."  So what this sentence means is

> At this point in the action, I think what would probably make sense would be you and me having a hug.

It's supposed to be funny because apparently Cloud Guy was not reading the other character well.

Comment: Thanks. Can this kind of line that imitates stage directions, i.e., (1), be easily used in everyday conversation? Also, is (2) a possible alternative to (1)?

Comment: (2) "Now I think we hug" means: *At this point in the script I think the stage directions say to hug*.  In other words, this is a memorization issue.  That's different from (1).  As to whether you can use it in your everyday conversations, that really depends on your environment.  If you are 16 (or 13 or 10) and you play with your friends by making videos together, and make up your scripts as you go along, or if this is common enough among you and your peers that you might easily do this as an activity together on the weekend, or ...

Comment: ... as part of a class or extracurricular activity at school, then yes, you can converse with each other at another time as though you were still in that activity, and probably be understood.